# How to use static members as template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code structure:

#### myClass.h

```
class myClass
{
public:
    void DoSomething(void);
};
```

#### myClass.cpp

```
#include myClass.h

static const unsigned length = 5;
static myArray<float, length> arrayX;

void myClass::DoSomething(void)
{
    // does something using length and array X
}
```

Now I want to convert the static variable defined at the file scope to be static members of the class. I do the following;

#### myClass.h

```
class myClass
{
    static const unsigned length;
    static myArray<float,length> arrayX;

public:
    void DoSomething(void);
};
```

#### myClass.cpp

```
#include myClass.h

const unsigned myClass::length = 5;
myArray<float, length> myClass::arrayX;

void myClass::DoSomething(void)
{
    // does something using length and array X
}
```

However, I get an error:

> C2975: 'Length' : invalid template argument for 'myArray', expected compile-time constant expression myClass.h

I do understand I get this error because length is not initialized in the header file yet.  How can I get around this?

Comment: Surely as you scrolled past the preview to click the Submit button, you would see the formatting is messed up. I attempted to fix it, but you've posted not "real" code, (missing `class` keyword, `Length` versus `length`.), so it's not exact.

Comment: Why do you need the template parameter to be determined by a static const member instead of a plain const?  That value cannot change at runtime no matter what you do.  Just make it a const.  reuse the const as the initializer for the static const member if you want to have it's value also available.

Comment: And now you roll it back, once again ignoring the preview...sigh. *Twice?* Wow. Last time.

Comment: Please post an actual minimal compilable example. This will help us a lot and maybe solve your problem before even posting it.

Answer (score 4):

It needs to be a constant expression, so the best you can do is move `= 5` to the header.

Comment: This is legal (and probably preferable) since the `static const` and the fact that it is an integral type qualify it as a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I was wondering if there is a way to get around this.

Look at your code again. That `myArray<float,length>` is declared as a class data member in the header.
In order for the compiler to know what `myClass` is, it must know the full definition of that data member. But the full definition of `myArray<float,length>` in turn requires `length` to be known, because without its template arguments, `myArray` is not a type, but a template, and data members must be types, not class templates.

From this it's clear that, in order to have a `myArray` instance as a class member, the `length` must be known when the class is compiled, `myArray` is to be a member of.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
myArray<float, myClass::length> myClass::arrayX;
               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

You may also need to change header:

```
class myClass
{
    static const unsigned length = 5;
```

and change definition of myClass::length in .cpp to not contain "= 5" (or remove it completly).